# Why use NSAutoreleasePool?

Tags: objective-c

Consider the following program:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) { 
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
    // Insert code here... 
    NSLog(@"Programming is Fun !"); 
    [pool drain]; 
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why `pool` is needed there as the same program can be also written as this:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) { 
    NSLog(@"Programming is Fun !"); 
    return 0;
}
```

What is a purpose of using an auto release pool? Why and when do we need them? Are they mandatory in every objective C program?

If i don't want to auto release any object, do I also need to use an Auto Release pool ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But if i don't want to auto release any object, then also do i need to use Auto Release pool ??

Also note that the Cocoa library uses `autorelease` extensively. So, even if you think you don't use the pool in your code, you need to prepare the pool.

Answer (score 11):

`NSObject` contains a neat function called `autorelease`. This means all objects in Objective-C contain this function.

This function inserts `self` into the autorelease pool, delaying the call to object's `release` function until the autorelease pool is deallocated. Most internal APIs use an autorelease pool, and beside the one located in `main()`, there is one allocated and deallocated in UIKit's main loop in every pass.

In short: it's the queue for delayed decrement of reference counter.

Example on where autorelease is hidden:

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"some string"];
```

This object is allocated, and autorelease is called on it. How would you use it yourself?

```
MyObject *obj = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Why is this good? When you return this object, the calling function does not need to take care to release this object, and optionally it can retain it (but doesn't have to).

---

To expand and clarify four years later:

While UIKit and AppKit create and drain an `NSAutoreleasePool` during the course of their main runloop, in your non-GUI program you need to create it yourself. Various code expects having an `NSAutoreleasePool` present, and since you didn't initialize a GUI framework nor you use one, there is no code that will magically create it for you.

While `NSLog()` and a constant `NSString` in your example don't require a pool, even the trivial `[NSMutableArray array]` does, given that it can actually be interpreted as `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]`.

Answer (score 3):

I have found reason...
"If a pool is not available, autoreleased objects do not get released and you leak memory. In this situation, your program will typically log suitable warning messages."

Comment: If you find some other answer particularly helpful, feel free to "up" it, and/or mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

You typically do not have to create an autorelease pool block yourself, or even see the code that is used to create one. three occasions when you might use your own autorelease pool blocks,

- If you are writing a program that is not based on a UI framework,
  such as a command-line tool.
- If you write a loop that creates many temporary objects - You may use
  an autorelease pool block inside the loop to dispose of those objects
  before the next iteration. Using an autorelease pool block in the
  loop helps to reduce the maximum memory footprint of the application.
- If you spawn a secondary thread - You must create your own
  autorelease pool block as soon as the thread begins executing;
  otherwise, your application will leak objects.

Answer (score 1):

A general introduction can be found on Apple's website:

- [Autorelease Pools](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) and [Ownership and Disposal](http://web.archive.org/web/20100816061019/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the NSAutoreleasePool [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: updated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsautoreleasepool